# count number of bit 1 in a file containing hex values

Tags: vim

Is there a quick way to count number of ones in a hex file?
The file is something like this representing sequences of hex values:

```
13
ff
a0
```

in this case the number of ones is 3 + 8 + 2 = 13 number of ones (after we convert to binary).
Now I have thousands of lines like that, is there a quick way to do that in vi command?

Answer (score 1):

(Assuming the file is ascii hex, if not writing something in python shouldn't be that hard)

With a little set up you could do this pretty quickly.

First create a file that will have the following.

```
let g:hex2popcount = {
            \ '0': 0, '1': 1, '2': 1, '3': 2,
            \ '4': 1, '5': 2, '6': 2, '7': 3,
            \ '8': 1, '9': 2, 'a': 2, 'b': 3,
            \ 'c': 2, 'd': 3, 'e': 3, 'f': 4}

function! Accum(var)
    let g:x += g:hex2popcount[a:var]
endfunction
```

The hex2popcount dict is a maps the 16 hex characters to a the count of number of one bits. We then create a function called Accum that will be used to keep track of how many bits we've seen. To run this on all hex digits in your file we will you substitute with an expression and the `n` flag which doesn't actually do any of the replacements.

```
let g:x = 0 | %s/\x/\=Accum(submatch(0))/gn | echo g:x
```

We set `g:x` to zero and then run `Accum(submatch(0))` on every hex digit in the file. When the substitute is done `g:x` contains the total number of one digits.

Make sure to source the file in vim. With `vim -S <file with accum function>` or `:source <file with accum function>` or just place the commands in your vimrc.

Relevant help pages are `:help sub-replace-expression` and `:help :s_flags`